# Hide The Author Name In Wordpress (Discord Embed)

Tags: wordpress, discord

Hey I know there is many topic about this But in my case it is different I am using Oxygen Builder here may i know how to remove it?
[enter image description here][1]

I want to remove that Highlighted word
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc0Ko.png

Answer (score 0):

If you go to customization and theme editor, you can find the file you have to edit "functions.php"

Add these lines of code to hide the user who created the page both on discord and on other pages.

```php
add_filter( 'oembed_response_data', 'disable_embeds_filter_oembed_response_data_' );
function disable_embeds_filter_oembed_response_data_( $data ) {
    unset($data['author_url']);
    unset($data['author_name']);
    return $data;
}
```